# Yahoo Mail Oauth + OpenID PHP sample Code?

Tags: php, email, oauth, openid, yahoo

I'm looking for a sample code for using Oauth + OpenID, to send and receive yahoo mail.

I checked yahoo developer site :

http://developer.yahoo.com/mail/code/

but I didn't find any sample on there.

do you have any references or sample codes which you can share them?

Comment: Try this , it has a generic example http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_OAuth/docs/latest/

Answer (score 0):

The [Yahoo! Social SDK](https://github.com/yahoo/yos-social-php5) has samples for OAuth+OpenID for other Yahoo! properties, but the samples should guide you well enough to implement them for Mail. You can also use the mail table on YQL for that, and the samples should be enough for this.